# What's wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This is my question: [Position of a electrical charge with mass at a given time under the influence of the electrical field of another charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437217/position-of-a-electrical-charge-with-mass-at-a-given-time-under-the-influence-of?noredirect=1#comment986147_437217)

It has been put on hold for reasons I can't achieve to understand

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Chair, Aaron Stevens,
>   Kyle Kanos, AccidentalFourierTransform, sammy gerbil yesterday Please
>   clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight
>   exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell
>   exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help
>   clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded to fit the
>   rules in the help center, please edit your question.

I even used bold text to underline the main point of my question.
Also, In the comment section, one guy is suggesting my question is a possible duplicate of this one:
  [What is the distance between two objects in space as a function of time, considering only the force of gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/217633/what-is-the-distance-between-two-objects-in-space-as-a-function-of-time-conside) 
What does gravity have to do with electrics charges in this context? I know that some formulas are similar and in some scenarios the workings are similar, but they are completely different things.

Can I do something to improve my question?

Answer (score 4):

First off, according to moderator view<sup>1</sup> of the [timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/437217/timeline) for the question, the five close votes included two for unclear, two for [homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/), and one for duplicate. The way the system responds when there are multiple close reasons given for a question is to pick one reason to display.

Your basic question, how one electrical charge moves in the presence of another electric charge, is a staple of introductory and advanced E&M courses.  In such a class, you would learn how to do this in many different situations: the two charges might have one or another mass ratio, or initial relative momenta, or impact parameter.  If you specified those things, you would be asking a homework-like question. Since you left them alone, there's not enough information to come up with a general answer to your question in a format that's a good fit for us.  That's probably the reason for the "unclear" and "homework-like" votes.

Since gravity and electromagnetism are both $1/r^2$ forces, gravitational trajectories follow the same mathematics as electrical trajectories (if the electrical interaction is attractive).  That's probably the reason for the duplicate vote.

I didn't cast any of those votes, but they all make sense to me.

---

<sup>1</sup> The diamond-moderators' view of the timeline contains some information that's hidden from ordinary users, including which users cast which type of close vote and other flag-type information that ought to remain private.

Comment: It's worth noting that there was also at least one flag on the post: the first close vote (mine) was cast through the review queue apparently, so someone must have flagged it to send it there. Flaggers also count as people who think the question should be closed.